# Is this bad code? If it is then how to work around it?

Tags: c#, interface, dependencies, circular-dependency

Is this considered circular dependency? I don't like that part where I have to pass the object itself to IRule... Is there a way to work around this?

```cs
  public interface IRule
  {
    void Apply(World world);
  }

  public class World
  {
    public List<IRule> Rules { get; set; }

    public void ApplyAllRules()
    {
        foreach (var rule in Rules)
        {
            //This is the part that I don't feel good about.
            rule.Apply(this);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What language is it in? C# I guess? Add a [c#] tag please.

Comment: @ciuak, Yes it is, C#

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: Shouldn't this go to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @KirkWoll, I'm not sure if it's wrong or not really, I just don't like it, and I want to make sure.

Comment: Why don't you like it?  The interface method `Apply` presumably requires an instance of `World` in order to function, and you're providing it.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Have you found a problem with it?

Comment: So this is ok! Isn't this a kind of circular dependency between IRule and World?

Comment: No not really, I didn't find any problem so far.

Comment: You can add a third type that gets the behavior/attributes you wish to obtain from `World`, gets a list of rules from somewhere (database, factory, etc.) and applies the behavior to the rules. This isn't better, per se, just a different approach.

Comment: Its not really a circular dependency. Sure, they know about each other, but creating a `World` won't create an `IRule` which then creates `Worlds`, etc. You are just passing the `IRule` a reference to it. No problems there.

Comment: This would create a circular dependency if one object or the other was moved to a different assembly however. Personally I think that's a code smell but it all depends on the implementation of `Apply`

Comment: There's really not a problem with this setup.  The only thing I would change is to have `IRule.Apply` take an `IWorld` (or some other interface that denotes the dependencies the concrete of `IRule` needs) instead of `World`.

Answer (score 1):

May be I am wrong but term "circular dependency" usually applied to references. What you have here is called "tight coupling". As *Gjeltema* mentioned, there is not much wrong here besides that preferably, you decouple your concrete objects.

```
public interface IRule
{
    void Apply(ILocation loc);
}

public class World : ILocation
{
    public List<IRule> Rules { get; set; }

    public void ApplyAllRules()
    {
        foreach (var rule in Rules)
        {

           rule.Apply(this);
        }
     }
 }
```

Now you have `IRule` communicating not to concrete object but to abstract interface. So, no 2 or more implementations are tightly coupled.